# How can I make a static bottom bar using Navigator with React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using the [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) which renders a Nav Bar and a Scene.

I've put the Bottom Nav Tray into the scene (as returned by `renderScene`) because I didn't know where else to put it.

The problem as you can see from the GIF is that react duplicates and animates the bottom bar too, creating a weird effect.

[image: Navigator animation]

Wrapping the `Navigator` in a `View` so I can add the Bottom Nav Tray as a sibling caused nothing to be rendered (seems like `Navigator` doesn't like to be wrapped).

How can I have a static bottom nav bar which isn't part of the transition animation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see RN Examples. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer ?

Also I found this article https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-experimental-part-3-adding-tabs-28a2c57356b6#.dmfu9zya9

Comment: That article looks like it solves the issue and the code looks good - will check it out on Monday and update this, thanks!